# Is it illegal to take pictures of the police in public in Germany?

Tags: privacy, police, germany, photography, schengen

I visited Cologne last year. I was taking a selfie with my phone's inner camera in front of a monument. I was unaware that my phone's outer camera was facing police officers conducting checks. One of them noticed it and approached me. He saw the picture of me with the monument instead of them, apologized for his misunderstanding then went back to work.

Is it an offense to photograph the police in Germany? I searched multiple websites but people gave very different answers and opinions, even on the same forum. I've never been charged for such offense anywhere in the EU but Germany is well known for its strict privacy laws and I do not wish to break any laws.

If it is indeed illegal and I get fined for it, will my past record add extra burden every time I visit Germany such as extra checks or questioning? Or is it something I can brush off since I live in Schengen anyway?

Comment: I think it's important to make the distinction between simply photographing and actually publishing/distributing. If you film police (or anyone) and then post a video online *in which you've censored their faces*, this seems like a very reasonable usage. But if faces (or other Personally Identifiable Information) are released, it could pose problems. But then... if while you're filming/photographing you capture someone committing a crime, that changes the circumstances yet again. The footage may become important evidence. Hopefully you can get answers that address these nuanced scenarios.

Comment: The **undercover** U-Bahn ticket inspectors do not allow their photography, and I would not be surprised if it is illegal to photograph them.

Comment: You mention that the police were 'conducting checks' without further information. Depending on what that means, it may be that the problem was photographing a protected security procedure (like how you can't photograph security at airports in the US), not photographing the police.

Answer (score 34):

### No, but...

It is not an offense to photograph people, especially if they are just caught at the edge or out of the center of the photography. **However** you do not have a right to photograph people either. In fact, under German law, you have to gain the consent of people that are the centerpiece of a photo for publication, or make the photo for a number of enumerated reasons. Among such is news reporting or documenting an ongoing crime - such material is made in the public interest. If you make a photo without consent or qualified reason, possession of the photo in general is no problem **but** you have no right to publish the photo.

To prevent such publication, the photographed person may demand deletion or destruction of the photo - however, following the demand is not explicitly required. Such a demand however is equivalent to an explicit demand to not publish the picture. As such, it gets really tricky for the photographer. **Publication without a release** (or a no-release statement) or one of the few excusing reasons **is a punishable offense**, which can land you in prison for up to one year. This stems from [Art. 2 GG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/gg/art_2.html), [§22](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/kunsturhg/__22.html), [§23](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/kunsturhg/__23.html) and [§33 Kunsturhebergesetz](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/kunsturhg/__33.html).

Hindering rescue services with your camera and creating photos of injured and vulnerable people is illegal under the same reasoning. Getting into the way of the police can constitute obstruction of emergency helpers atop of that. More on that specific part of German law can be learned [in this question](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/93644/10334). Do note that such photography can also be a crime under [§201a StGB](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/stgb/__201a.html), especially if your photography shows *someone* as vulnerable.

Another possibility for the approaching police might have been, that the policeman was interested to find out if you might have photographed or filmed the incident that led to the arrest. In that case, he might have requested a copy for evidentiary reasons.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147778/discussion-on-answer-by-trish-is-it-illegal-to-take-pictures-of-the-police-in-pu); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: I don't understand this answer: it seems that taking pictures is perfectly fine, but publishing is complicated. However, the OP was not asking about publishing?

Comment: @njzk2 you underestimate the reach of §201a StGB - even making such photos can be a breach of the personality rights. Also, because the photographed person often loses the control about publication of the picture once two people part, courts are often inclined to order deletion when a case about the "recht am eigenen Bild" is brought.

Comment: in fact, the highest german court has found ([Urt. v. 13. 10. 2015, Az. VI ZR 271/14](http://juris.bundesgerichtshof.de/cgi-bin/rechtsprechung/document.py?Gericht=bgh&Art=en&nr=73173&pos=0&anz=1)), that *intimate* photography that was created during a relationship can be demanded to be deleted if that relationship ends, as that material, if it would be published, would violate the highly intimate personality rights and **even the possession of them** by the ex-partner can violate those rights.

Comment: A photo on the streets is unlikely to violate those intimate personality rights unless the person is in the process of being made a victim of a crime or accident or directly after (see §201a (2) & (3) StGB). However, in a case of § 201a(2)/(3) StGB, the act of photography is illegal in itself unless there is a very compelling reason, which requires a very careful handling of the material after creation. E.g. media may make the material under the Medienprivileg, then must blur all faces of victims and control access to the unblurred material very tightly.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification. I found it was not obvious from your initial answer that even just taking the picture would be covered by those rules. Follow-up question: how does that cover security cameras? do they fall under qualified reason?

Comment: @njzk2 there is no *author* on a security camera, and they are covered under data protection laws in most cases.

Comment: surely the owner of the security camera is an author? otherwise my camera on a tripod doesn't have an author by that logic.

Comment: @njzk2 Security cam footage does not underly copyright (Urheberrecht) as it does not reach Schöpfungshöhe - it is not in the least artistic, has no artistic merit but is only utilitarian. It *also* has no author in the sense that there is no person that made **artistic** choices. In Germany, a security camera footage does not underly copyright at all. As such, it consequently also does not underly the Kunsturhebergesetz.

Comment: I am not allowed to take a picture that includes the recognizable face of someone because I'm capable of artistic choice? that's a convoluted argument... How is it related to privacy, whether or not the image was made with "artistic" choice?

Comment: @njzk2 No, that is not the argument. Just that under german law, the owner of the security camera has no Urheberrechte (=copyright) and can not limit publication or non-publication on that basis.

Comment: so are you saying that the footage from a security camera can never be published because no-one owns it? or that it can always be published, because it has no author?

Comment: @njzk2 No. I am saying that it is **without** urheberrecht, not that is without owner. It is *public domain*, but the only copy is owned by someone. **but** they also have to follow laws about personality rights and can't just publish that material based on those - just that it is *other* laws like GDPR and §201a STGB that limit *that* material

Answer (score 8):

[england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)

**NO**

The Metropolitan Police offer the following clarity (which is reproduced in similar terms by the other 42 police forces and various law enforcement agencies):

> [**Freedom to photograph and film**](https://www.met.police.uk/advice/advice-and-information/ph/photography-advice#:%7E:text=Freedom%20to%20photograph%20and%20film,photographing%20incidents%20or%20police%20personnel.)
>
> Members of the public and the media do not need a permit to film or photograph in public places and police have no power to stop them filming or photographing incidents or police personnel.

---

<sub>By way of some background: there has been some misunderstanding and misuse of the stop and search powers under [section 43](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2000/11/section/43?timeline=false) Terrorism Act 2000.  The issue being the officer's reasonable suspicion the person stopped may be a terrorist which, on occasion, was not subjectively reasonable.</sub>

---

<sub>Although tagged [germany](/questions/tagged/germany), I have answered according to the [LawSE Help Centre](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): "*we expect and encourage answers dealing with other jurisdictions ... please tag your answer using the tag markdown: [tag: some-tag]*"</sub>

Comment: The Metropolitan Police are not in Germany :)

Comment: @DavidPostill please see my second footnote, which I omitted in error first time round

Comment: If that is indeed the policy, should the question title be edited to remove "from Germany"?

Comment: @preferred_anon I don't think so, and if such a policy change is proposed then I would vote against it. FYI LawSEMeta has already discussed this, for example at [Jurisdictions in answers](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1710/35069)

Comment: @Rick I think that Meta thread is good and I agree with the practice of providing answers for unmentioned jurisdictions. But surely it's confusing for the title to explicitly say "in Germany" and for the answers to contradict it? That's the only point I was making (and I don't understand why you would vote against it). I'm not advocating for the question body to be changed, for example.

Comment: @preferred_anon No. This answer is **exactly** how it is supposed to work.

Comment: IMO the jurisdiction should also be mentioned  in the answer itself. Tagging may be sufficient technically, but it is self-evident that it isn't sufficient to avoid confusion, based on these comments.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, usually it is.

The more specific answer is: it depends. There is no specific law that makes it illegal to photograph police per se. However Germany has fairly strict regulations towards privacy and right to your own image and it is usually illegal to photograph a person without their consent if their face is visible in details. This also includes policemen on duty.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: does this add to the existing answers?